# guild.text_channels only returns 1 channel instead of all channels

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

When I use ctx.guild.text_channels and print the variable that I assigned to that it only shows the very first text channel that is in the discord server

I have tried looking in the documentation of discord rewrite if there is some kind of loop I have to use but could not find any. So i beleive I am doing something wrong.

Just to inform you guys I have member: discord.Member because I am going to use it later on.

Discord guild channel list: http://prntscr.com/prdcaa

```py
@bot.command(pass_contect=True)
async def check_client_channel(ctx, member: discord.Member):
    channels = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.text_channels)
    print(channels)
    channel_name = member.display_name + "-" + member.discriminator
```

Result when I execute the function:

`test2`

Expected result: (something similair to)

`["test2", "general", "test", "testing-2611"]`

Comment: From the documentation - ```A helper that returns the first element in the iterable that meets all the traits passed in attrs```. This means that ```utils.get``` will only return one value. ```ctx.guild.text_channels``` is already an iterable which contains the text channels so you don't need to use ```.get```

Answer (score 0):

This one is in `rewrite/master` version

```py
@bot.command()
async def on(msg):
    chans=msg.guild.text_channels
    print([i.name for i in chans])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like `channels = [discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.text_channels)]`. Also `pass_contect=True` has a typo(or idk python). I think it should be `pass_context=True`.